# Keith-Wood Datepick (month to a line)

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I want to use keith wood datepick as it is in the example :
[here](http://keith-wood.name/datepick.html?#layout)

the first one that draws a month in one line.

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
<title>jQuery Datepicker</title>
<style type="text/css">

    #listRender { font-size: 11px; }
    #listRender .month { clear: left; border: none;
        border-right: 1px solid #ccc; text-align: center; }
    #listRender .month div { float: left; width: 9.5em;
        padding-right: 0.5em; text-align: right; }
    #listRender ul { float: left; margin: 0em; padding: 0em;
        list-style: none; overflow: hidden; }
    #listRender ul.days { margin-left: 10em; text-align: center; }
    #listRender ul.days span { background-color: #777; color: #fff; }
    #listRender li { float: left; width: 1.75em; margin: 0em; border: 1px solid #aaa; }
    #listRender li a { display: block; width: 100%; padding: 0.125em;
        background-color: #eee; color: #000; text-decoration: none; }
    #listRender li span { display: block; width: 100%; padding: 0.125em;
        background-color: #fff; color: #888; }
    #listRender li .weekend { background-color: #ddd; }
    #listRender li .highlight { background-color: #f08080; }
    #listRender li .selected { background-color: #777; }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.datepick.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {

        $('#inlineDatepicker').datepick({monthsToShow: [6, 1], showOtherMonths: true,
    onSelect: function(date) { alert('You picked ' + date); },
    renderer: {picker: '<div><ul class="days">' +
        '{weekHeader}{weekHeader}{weekHeader}{weekHeader}{weekHeader}{weekHeader}' +
        '</ul><div>{months}</div></div>',
        monthRow: '<div>{months}</div>',
        month: '<div class="month"><div>{monthHeader:M yyyy}</div><ul>{weeks}</ul></div>',
        weekHeader: '{days}',
        dayHeader: '<li>{day}</li>',
        week: '{days}',
        day: '<li>{day}</li>',
        monthSelector: '.month',
        daySelector: 'li',
        rtlClass: 'rtl',
        multiClass: 'multi',
        defaultClass: 'default',
        selectedClass: 'selected',
        highlightedClass: 'highlight',
        todayClass: 'today',
        otherMonthClass: 'other-month',
        weekendClass: 'weekend',
        commandClass: 'cmd-',
        disabledClass: 'disabled'}});

});

function showDate(date) {
    alert('The date chosen is ' + date);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>jQuery Datepicker</h1>
<p>This page demonstrates the very basics of the
    <a href="http://keith-wood.name/datepick.html">jQuery Datepicker plugin</a>.
    It contains the minimum requirements for using the plugin and
    can be used as the basis for your own experimentation.</p>
<p>For more detail see the <a href="http://keith-wood.name/datepickRef.html">documentation reference</a> page.</p>
<p>A popup datepicker <input type="text" id="popupDatepicker"></p>
<p>Or inline</p>
<div id="inlineDatepicker"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

any way, it does not work at all.
it is perfect for my application. yet I can not make it work.
where is the problem and how to fix it?
regards

Comment: did you download the plugin and add it to your page **after** jQuery?

Comment: yes exactly!,
`<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.datepick.js"></script>`

Comment: You've also wrapped this code around `$(function() { /* Code here */ });` ?

Comment: yes, sure,
I have updated the question and added all the example.